# android.widget.LinearLayout does not have a NavController set

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am trying to set clickListener on recyclerview items but I'm getting following error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: View
> android.widget.LinearLayout{dc43be8 VFE...C.. ...P.... 0,0-739,207}
> does not have a NavController set

`adapter`

```
class OrdersAdapter(val context: Context?, private var orderList: OrderArr) : RecyclerView.Adapter<OrdersAdapter.OrderViewHolder>() {
    lateinit var navController: NavController

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): OrdersAdapter.OrderViewHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
                R.layout.orders_items,
                parent,
                false
        )
        return OrdersAdapter.OrderViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: OrdersAdapter.OrderViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = orderList.data[position]
        holder.orderId.text = "ID " + currentItem.id
        holder.price.text = "Rp. " + currentItem.price + " /KG"
        holder.status.text = currentItem.status

        holder.apply {
            with(holder.itemView) {
                itemView.setOnClickListener {
                    navController = Navigation.findNavController(itemView) //<-- error line
                    val bundle = bundleOf("orderIDArgument" to  holder.orderId.text.toString())
                    navController!!.navigate(R.id.action_ordersFragment_to_orderDetailFragment, bundle)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = orderList.data.size


    class OrderViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        val orderId: TextView =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.order_Iid)
        val status: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.order_status_text)
        val price: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.order_price_text)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Navcontroller hasn't been properly initialised when you are trying to use it.

One way to get around this is to pass it as a constructor argument for the adapter from the enclosing/calling class and the assign it to a local variable. Then you can use it.

```
OrdersAdapter(val context: Context?, private var orderList: OrderArr, navController : Navcontroller)

private var _navController = navController
```

In the onClick listener:

```
_navcontroller.navigate(*bundle*, *directions*)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for respond. do you mean I add `navController : Navcontroller` to my adapter file? if yes then in my fragment recycler adapter will require extra value, what should I pass in there?

Comment: When you call your Adapter you pass in a Navcontroller. This can now be used by the Adapter.

Comment: you're confusing me here is my fragment `laundriesRecycler.adapter = OrdersAdapter(context, list)` and here is my adapter based on your suggestion `class OrdersAdapter(val context: Context?, private var orderList: OrderArr, navController : Navcontroller) : RecyclerView.Adapter<OrdersAdapter.OrderViewHolder>() {...}` in my fragment `OrdersAdapter(context, list)` after list now expects 3rd parameter

Comment: In your fragment where you are calling your adapter - do you have a navcontroller there? If yes then pass this in when you call OrdersAdapter - so OrdersAdapter(context, list, navcontroller).

Comment: no i don't have any use of `NavController` in that fragment

Comment: Ok. Well you either have to pass one in, or you have to create one in this adapter class before you set the onclicklistener.